# Set keys in org-columns after startup

Tags: key-bindings

I would like to set (or unset in this case) keys in the `org-columns-map` at startup but when I use `"org-columns"` nothing happens. If I use `"org"` instead I get errors that org-columns-map is not defined.

```el
    (with-eval-after-load "org-columns"
     (define-key org-columns-map (kbd "a") nil)
     (define-key org-columns-map (kbd "o") nil)
     (define-key org-columns-map (kbd "c") nil)
     (define-key org-columns-map (kbd "n") nil)
     (define-key org-columns-map (kbd "p") nil)
     (define-key org-columns-map (kbd "g") nil)
    )
```

If I use `eval-region` the definitions work as expected, but they do not set at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no file called `org-columns` so the `eval-after-load` never triggers. The variable `org-columns-map` is defined in the file `org-colview.el`, so use

```el
(with-eval-after-load "org-colview"
     (define-key org-columns-map (kbd "a") nil)
     (define-key org-columns-map (kbd "o") nil)
     (define-key org-columns-map (kbd "c") nil)
     (define-key org-columns-map (kbd "n") nil)
     (define-key org-columns-map (kbd "p") nil)
     (define-key org-columns-map (kbd "g") nil)
)
```

You can do `C-h v org-columns-map RET` to find out in which file the variable is defined (and of course that is not limited to `org-columns-map`: you can do that with any variable).